# Finding $u<v$ such that $\int_u^v f(x)dx \neq 0, (e^{ix_nu})_n$ and $(e^{ix_nv})_n$ converge in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $(x_n)_n$ be sequencd of real numbers such that for $\lambda$-almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}, \lim_{n\to +\infty}e^{ixx_n}$ in $\mathbb{C}.$ let $f$ be the corresponding limit (defined almost everywhere).

Can you find $u<v$ such that $\int_u^v f(x)dx \neq 0, (e^{ix_nu})_n$ and $(e^{ix_nv})_n$ converge in $\mathbb{C}$ ? Justify.

This question is related to [If $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ is a Borel function such that $|f|=1,$ then there exist $\alpha<\beta$ such that $\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}f(x)dx \neq 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4540932/if-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbc-is-a-borel-function-such-that-f-1-then-the)

Comment: Since $|f|=1$ where defined hence ae ($|e^{ixx_n}|=1, x, x_n$ real) the result follows from the linked question (find first $u_0,v_0$ where the integral is non zero, but then since $f$ is defined ae there are $u,v$ in the definition set of $f$ and close enough to $u_0,v_0$ st the integral is not zero as the difference between the two integrals is at most $|u-u_0|+|v-v_0|$ because $|f|=1$ ae)

Comment: Can you explain why if the difference was at most $|u-u_0|+|v-v_0|$ then it should be non zero

Comment: The property of being non zero is open - in other words if $a\ne 0$ then $a+z\ne 0$ for all $|z|<|a|/2$ so in particular if the original integral was $a$, choosing $u,v$ close enough to $u_0,v_0$ so $|u-u_0|+|v-v_0|<|a|/2$ shows that the new integral is not zero